# Comparing radiation levels - Chernobyl vs Moon

Tags: radiation, nuclear-engineering

How radiation from Chernobyl disaster compares to cosmic radiation on the surface of the Moon (effect on human cells and electronic devices)?

Why Chernobyl liquidators suffered heavily from radiation, when on the Moon people and electronic devices were not affected?

Comment: Well, what radiation on the moon are you worried about?

Comment: What has your research shown? What are the radiation levels in the moon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The radiation in space has a different character than the radiation in Chernobyl after the disaster.

In Chernobyl, the most dangerous radiation was gamma and neutron radiation from the radioactive fuel, gamma from the materials around (in the first days mainly Tellurium 132 and Caesium 134, 137) and (mainly in the first few days) beta radiation from Iodine 131 from dust inhaled or food ingested.

In space, the prevalent concern is due to protons and other heavy particles (nuclei of helium and others).

There are ways to compare numerically effect of these different radiations on a person, for example by comparing absorbed dose per hour. However, absorbed dose quantifies only heat effects of the radiation. It is only a rough indication of subsequent long-term biological effects of radiation (cancer, leukaemia).

For this reason, RBE factor was introduced which gives an indication of how much worse the radiation is than gamma radiation, for the same absorbed dose. Taking this into account, the effective dose is given in rems or sierverts. However, this factor is not well understood for cosmic radiation and can be different for different organs.

It is hard to find reliable numbers on dose rates for the Moon environment and for Chernobyl the numbers vary greatly depending on where the person was present.

I found some information on estimated total dose for the Apollo astronauts. According to https://www.nature.com/articles/srep29901, which references

Bailey, J. Radiation protection and instrumentation. 105–113 (US Governement Printing Office, Washington D.C., 1975)

> The average radiation dose for the seven deceased Apollo crew was 0.59 ± 0.15 cGy (range 0.18–1.14 cGy)

Assuming RBE=1 (that is a big if), this would be equivalent absorbed dose around 6 mSv.

According to https://www.oecd-nea.org/rp/chernobyl/c04.html, section "The liquidators",

> information is available on the doses received by the 237 persons who were placed in hospitals and diagnosed as suffering from acute radiation syndrome. Using biological dosimetry, it was estimated that 41 of these patients received whole-body doses from external irradiation in the range 1-2 Sv, that 50 received doses between 2 and 4 Sv, that 22 received between 4 and 6 Sv, and that the remaining 21 received doses between 6 and 16 Sv.

For the subsequent cleanup operations, the above documents says

> The liquidators were initially subjected to a radiation dose limit for one year of 250 mSv. In 1987 this limit was reduced to 100 mSv and in 1988 to 50 mSv (Ba93).

Thus the Apollo astronauts received much less effective dose than the average for the Chernobyl's liquidators. It seems like the radiation dose due to few day trip outside Earth's protection, including a short stay on the Moon surface, is not too dangerous. Of course, this depends on time of flight, as the cosmic radiation can get significantly more intense in periods of solar activity. Also on Moon's surface there may be areas more radioactive than the ones American astronauts visited.

Answer (score 3):

The average effective dose caused by cosmic radiation on the surface of the Moon is about 380 mSv (solar minimum) and 110 mSv (solar maximum) per year.[1] The longest time on the lunar surface (Eugene Cernan and Harrison Schmitt of Apollo 17) was about 75 hours.

The so-called liquidators were recovery operation workers, active in 1986–1990 at the nuclear power plant or in the zone surrounding it for the decontamination, construction of the sarcophagus, and other clean-up operations. (This group does not include those involved in emergency measures during the first day of the accident.)

The main exposure pathway for the recovery operation workers was external gamma radiation from the radioactive material deposited onto the ground and building surfaces. (Furthermore, there was exposure of the skin to external beta radiation.) The mean dose was about 150 mSv in 1986. (Most recovery operation workers spent less than six months on site during their first mission.) For most workers, the dose limit was 250 mSv in 1986.[2]

---

[1] Guenther Reitz, Thomas Berger, Daniel Matthiae: "Planetary and Space Science
Volume 74, Issue 1, December 2012, Pages 78-83", *Planetary and Space Science,* Volume 74, Issue 1, December 2012, Pages 78-83.

[2] UNSCEAR 2008 Report: "Sources and effects of ionizing radiation", Volume II, Annex D - Health effects due to radiation from the Chernobyl accident